# how to make the text stay in the search box after clicking the search button or next-page button?

Tags: python, html, flask, web

here is what I am passing in:

```
return render_template("results.html" query_text=query_text)
```

here is the template

```
<form action="{{ url_for('results') }}" name="search" method="post">
<label for="query">Query:</label>
<input type="text" value="{{query_text}}" id="query" name="query"   size=50 required>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

but the text won't stay in the search bar, how do you fix it? Thanks

I am using html, flask and python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Reason is when you click the button the request goes back to the server to render the new/results page. You either need to update your ninja template to to take a variable with the search query (so it gets returned in the returned html). Or you need to move to javascript to update your page but that's more complicated

Comment: Thank-you @rayad, I think i have the variable for my search query, its the query_text, and then I pass it into the template as   |value="{{query_text}}"|, but it still won't keep the text in the search bar.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I didn't notice that! It looks right to me, make sure its getting passed correctly from your route, and make sure that the variables are spent the same!

Comment: Thank-you so much @rayad, it worked! Have a wonderful day!